# Avoid binding multiple events on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm fetching cshtml in my .net project through ajax, after biding data to dom successfully, initializing datatable on it with export to excel feature,

but when you fetch data more than a time (user using filers), datatable is binding (appending) event to export button every time, and user ends up downloading multiple excel files at once.

I have replicated `cshtml` and `ajax` method with `data` and `getCSHTML` methods.

Steps to reproduce issue.

1. Click on <kbd>Get Data</kbd> button.
2. Click on <kbd>Export Data</kbd> button (Only one file will be downloaded).
3. Go back to step 1 and 2, repeat it without refreshing the browser tab, you will end up downloading multiple excel file on a single click.

I have tried, `.off()` , `.unbind()` and `.bind()`, but no help.

```js
var data = '<table id="example"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td></tr><tr><td>Angelica Ramos</td><td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2009/10/09</td></tr><tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td></tr><tr><td>Bradley Greer</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>41</td><td>2012/10/13</td></tr><tr><td>Brenden Wagner</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>28</td><td>2011/06/07</td></tr><tr><td>Brielle Williamson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2012/12/02</td></tr><tr><td>Bruno Nash</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>38</td><td>2011/05/03</td></tr><tr><td>Caesar Vance</td><td>Pre-Sales Support</td><td>New York</td><td>21</td><td>2011/12/12</td></tr><tr><td>Cara Stevens</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>New York</td><td>46</td><td>2011/12/06</td></tr><tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td></tr></tbody></table>'

function getCSHTML() {
  $("#masterPage").html(data);

  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
      var $buttons = $('.dt-buttons').hide();
      if ($('#exportLink').length > 0) {
        $('#exportLink').on('change', function() {
          var btnClass = $(this).find(":selected")[0].id ?
            '.buttons-' + $(this).find(":selected")[0].id :
            null;
          if (btnClass) $buttons.find(btnClass).click();
        })
      }
      $('#exportToExcel').on('click', function() {
        $('.buttons-excel').click()
      })
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="getCSHTML()">Get Data</button>
<button id="exportToExcel">Export Data</button>

<div id="masterPage"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) at the start of your function with this line

```
$("#exportToExcel").unbind("click")
```

Example :

```js
var data = '<table id="example"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td></tr><tr><td>Angelica Ramos</td><td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2009/10/09</td></tr><tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td></tr><tr><td>Bradley Greer</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>41</td><td>2012/10/13</td></tr><tr><td>Brenden Wagner</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>28</td><td>2011/06/07</td></tr><tr><td>Brielle Williamson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2012/12/02</td></tr><tr><td>Bruno Nash</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>38</td><td>2011/05/03</td></tr><tr><td>Caesar Vance</td><td>Pre-Sales Support</td><td>New York</td><td>21</td><td>2011/12/12</td></tr><tr><td>Cara Stevens</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>New York</td><td>46</td><td>2011/12/06</td></tr><tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td></tr></tbody></table>'

function getCSHTML() {
  $("#masterPage").html(data);

  $("#exportToExcel").unbind("click"); // unbind here

  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
      var $buttons = $('.dt-buttons').hide();
      if ($('#exportLink').length > 0) {
        $('#exportLink').on('change', function(e) {
          var btnClass = $(this).find(":selected")[0].id ?
            '.buttons-' + $(this).find(":selected")[0].id :
            null;
          if (btnClass) $buttons.find(btnClass).click();
        })
      }
      $('#exportToExcel').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.buttons-excel').click()
      })
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="getCSHTML()">Get Data</button>
<button id="exportToExcel">Export Data</button>

<div id="masterPage"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to move export function outside of initComplete it works like a charm

Comment: I can't, I need to attach event to button on table init.

Comment: but why; is export button dynamically generated

Comment: @AbhishekPandey even if you could it wouldn't fix the problem, this is an untested non working answer.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Exactly

Comment: @irfandar i need to bind it every time datatable initiates, if I move it outside the init, it will be bind only when page will be reload.

Comment: Try my suggestion to see if it works; I tried it and it works perfectly.